# How to sort by padded string attribute in python using key functions

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose l is a list of objects of class c with a String attribute x.
l should be sorted based on the following criteria:
For any two items: split x at the last slash-character, take the suffix, add a padding of zeros at the front of the two to make them equal in length and compare them alphabetically.
I read that one should use the key function for sorting in python. However I can't figure out any way to achieve the required sorting criteria this way. If key functions aren't the right way to achieve the required sorting, I'm happy for solutions using the "correct" way.

Comment: Is the RH after the last slash always shorter than the prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky to do using a key function; it would be easier to use a custom comparison function. Python 2 supports custom comparison functions for `sort`, but Python 3 does not. However, sorting with a key function is *much* more efficient than using a custom comparison function: the key function is only called once for each item in the list, whereas a custom comparison function must be called for *every* comparison made.

The "key" to solving this problem is to realize that it doesn't matter how many zeroes are prepended to each string, so long as the length of two strings being compared is equal. So we just need to determine the length of the longest string in the data, and pad all strings to that length.

To determine that length, we can use a relatively simple generator expression that uses `rsplit` to get the length of the portion of the string after the final slash and passes those lengths to the built-in `max` function. And we can then use that maximum length in our key function.

The following code is for Python 2, but it will work on Python 3 if you fix the print statements in the `show` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

data = [
    'a/bc/this',
    'a/bc/is',
    'a/bc/a',
    'a/bc/short',
    'a/bc/test',
    'a/bc/123',
    'a/bc/24',
    'a/bc/5',
]

#Simple sequence printer
def show(seq):
    for row in seq:
        print row
    print

#Get maximum length of the string after the last slash in each data string
maxlen = max(len(s.rsplit('/', 1)[1]) for s in data)

#Key function that pads the string after the last slash
key = lambda s: s.rsplit('/', 1)[1].rjust(maxlen, '0')

#Test the key function
show([(s, key(s)) for s in data])

new_data = sorted(data, key=key)
show(new_data)
```

**output**

```
('a/bc/this', '0this')
('a/bc/is', '000is')
('a/bc/a', '0000a')
('a/bc/short', 'short')
('a/bc/test', '0test')
('a/bc/123', '00123')
('a/bc/24', '00024')
('a/bc/5', '00005')

a/bc/5
a/bc/a
a/bc/24
a/bc/is
a/bc/123
a/bc/test
a/bc/this
a/bc/short
```

---

I don't know the exact details of how Timsort sorts using a key function, but it's equivalent to:

1. Turn the list of items into a list of (key, item) tuples.
2. Sort the list of tuples, only sorting on the key & ignoring the item.
3. Rebuild a new list of items by stripping them from the tuples in the sorted list.

This is only a rough guide, since Timsort is written in C.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I got one follow up question, where can I find the documentation of the key-based sorting used in python? Just of curiosity on the computational complexity of the sorting algorithm.

Comment: @soriak: I'm glad you like it! I've added some info about the key sorting process to the end of my answer. Python's sort function is called Timsort. It was developed for use in Python but it's so good that it's been adopted by several other platforms. For details, see the Wikipedia [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) page; you can also read [Tim Peter's own notes](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt) in the Python sources.